# AdHoc Installation fails on older iPad running iOS 5.1.1 - /usr/libexec/installd crashes

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an app that I am distributing using AdHoc - that works fine (using testflightapp.com) on most devices, however I have two older ones which run iOS 5.1.1 and iOS 4.3 respectively and on those I just can't get the app installed.

The app has been built using XCode 5.1.1 and deployment target of iOS 4.3.

The installation goes about 75% through (i.e. icon shows on home screen, progress indicator starts running up to about 75%), then an error message is shown: "Unable to Download Application" - ... could not be downloaded at this time.

Checking the logs I found crash of /usr/libexec/installd - see below.

Btw the same happens when I try to install the app via iTunes, so it's not related to Testflight.

Any hints on why this happens and how I can fix it would be highly appreciated.

Patrick

---

```
Incident Identifier: 55B1E8CF-AF1B-4E2E-9445-9001A1E9181F
CrashReporter Key:   2c384f06f249d55ddbb948525a8bef5b10aef496
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         installd [301]
Path:            /usr/libexec/installd
Identifier:      installd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2014-08-15 19:45:40.965 +1000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  2

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35b5c004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35b5c1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35aca3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35ac90ea __CFRunLoopRun + 818
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35a4c49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35a4c366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   installd                        0x00070bb8 0x64000 + 52152
7   installd                        0x00065856 0x64000 + 6230
8   installd                        0x0006528c 0x64000 + 4748

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35b5c3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33e8fea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33e8fbc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34d0c884 strlen + 12
1   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x37151e2c std::string::operator+=(char const*) + 8
2   libmis.dylib                    0x32d7c43e ___lldb_unnamed_function268$$libmis.dylib + 226
3   libmis.dylib                    0x32d728bc ___lldb_unnamed_function40$$libmis.dylib + 112
4   libmis.dylib                    0x32d784ee ___lldb_unnamed_function174$$libmis.dylib + 298
5   libmis.dylib                    0x32d747aa ___lldb_unnamed_function81$$libmis.dylib + 166
6   libmis.dylib                    0x32d71b2a ___lldb_unnamed_function22$$libmis.dylib + 14
7   libmis.dylib                    0x32d71fa2 MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo + 266
8   installd                        0x00067b56 0x64000 + 15190
```

Comment: Does this app package contain 64bit architecture?

Comment: it uses the standard architecture settings, which now are armv7, armv7s and arm64, so I guess that means yes ?

Comment: I just build a version without armv7s and arm64 and that installs fine - thanks Kerni !!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible to install one build that includes arm64 architecture on devices running iOS 5.x other than using the App Store.

So to install development or ad-hoc builds on a device with iOS 5.x or 4.x you need to make an extra build that does **not** include 64 bit architecture.

When submitting to the App Store, the build can contain all architectures, and Apple will modify the binary on their end so the problem won't occur in that case.