# cannot run application with 64bit support on iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit

In order to support 64 bit in iOS apps, 'deployment target' must be set to at least 5.1.1: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html

As I understand it - it means that a device with iOS 5.1.1 (32 bit) should be supported (but OS below 5.1.1 is not supported). However, when the app is installed using xCode on iOS 5.1.1 I get the following error:

> Xcode cannot install or launch applications supporting the 64-bit architecture on devices running iOS versions prior to 6.0. This configuration is supported for distribution through the iOS App Store, but cannot be used during development with Xcode. To continue, edit the Run scheme action and select a build configuration that does not include the 64-bit architecture.

The error says that this this version (5.1.1) supported on appstore but not on xcode. Does it mean that when the app is uploaded to appstore it will work properly on 5.1.1, but I just can't test 5.1.1 using xcode..?

*It works on iOS6 and above.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324787/adhoc-installation-fails-on-older-ipad-running-ios-5-1-1-usr-libexec-installd

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.  I'm building on XCode 6.3 with the iOS 8.3 SDK.  I can run my app on iOS 5.1.1 using an armv7 architecture, but not "armv7 arm64". My QA dept is testing this via ipa installs using iTunes.